# How to group fields when serialising object with Marshmallow?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow, flask-marshmallow

## Problem

How to group fields together when serialising a flat-structured SQLAlchemy object with Marshmallow without changing the flat data structure in the background?

## Example

Suppose a SQLAlchemy model in a Flask app like this:

```py
from app import db # db using SQLAlchemy

class Data(db.Model):
  x = db.Column(db.Float(), required=True)
  y = db.Column(db.Float(), required=True)
  d = db.Column(db.Float())
```

How can I serialise this object so that `x` and `y` are nested into `coordinates`, while maintaining a flat data structure in the background (the model)? The output should look something like this:

```
{
  "coordinates": {
    "x": 10.56
    "y": 1
  },
  "d": 42.0
}
```

The problem arises specifically because I use the `Data` schema with the `many=True` option. The initialisation is roughly:

```py
schema_data = MomentData()
schema_datas = MomentData(many=True)
```

---

## Solution Candidates

So this is what I've tried so far, but none of them seemed to work.

### Creating a second Schema

Adding a second schema and modifying the `Data` schema from before yields:

```py
class CoordinatesSchema(Schema):
  x = fields.Float(required=True)
  y = fields.Float(required=True)

class DataSchema(Schema):
  coordinates = fields.Nested(coordinatesSchema, required=True)
  d = fields.Float()
```

Having that in place raises the problem of having to go through every `Data` item and manually adding the `Coordinates` schema. My data is coming from a SQLAlchemy query returning a list of `Data` objects, so that I can easily dump them using `schema_datas`.

### Using `fields.Dict`

Since Marshmallows `fields` module offers a dictionary, I tried that as well.

```py
def DataSchema(Schema):
  coordinates = fields.Dict(keys=fields.String(),
                            value=fields.Float(),
                            required=True,
                            default={
                                 "x": Data.x,
                                 "y": Data.y
                            })
  d = fields.Float()
```

Doesn't seem to work either, because Marshmallow can't find `Data.x` and `Data.y` automatically when using `schema_datas.dump()`.

### Using Self-Nesting

The most logical solution path would be to self-nest. But (from what I understood reading [the documentation](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/nesting.html)) self-nesting only refers to nesting one or more *other* instances within the object. I want to nest the *same* instance.

```py
class DataSchema(Schema):
  x = fields.Float(required=True, load_only=True)
  y = fields.Float(required=True, load_only=True)

  coordinates = fields.Nested(
        lambda: DataSchema(only=('x', 'y')),
        dump_only=True)
```

But unfortunately this also didn't work.

### Using Decorator `@pre_dump`

Inspired by [this issue on Marshmallow's Github page](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/985), I tried to use the `@pre_dump` decorator to achieve the desired outcome, but failed again.

```py
class CoordinatesSchema(Schema):
  x = fields.Float(required=True)
  y = fields.Float(required=True)

class DataSchema(Schema):
  coordinates = fields.Nested(coordinatesSchema, required=True)
  d = fields.Float()

  @pre_dump
  def group_coordinates(self, data, many):
    return {
      "coordinates": {
        "x": data.x,
        "y": data.y
        },
      "d": data.d
    }
```

But I can't figure out how to do it properly...

---

So my question is, what am I doing wrong and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't see why the pre_dump fails. I'd rather use post_dump to do that. It's simpler to modify the dump only where needed. The pre_dump must recreate the whole object, which sucks.

Comment: I think the [Pluck](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference.html#marshmallow.fields.Pluck) field does what you want. I don't know how it works with SQLAlchemy, though.

Comment: Okay thank you Jérôme! I'll change it to post_dump and try again.

Oh and I think Pluck could do the trick, thank you! I'll try it tomorrow and report back, if it worked!

Answer (score 0):

After struggling myself with same issue, here is the solution (not so far from what you suggested) :

```
class CoordinatesSchema(Schema):
  x = fields.Float(required=True)
  y = fields.Float(required=True)

class DataSchema(Schema):
  coordinates = fields.Nested(coordinatesSchema, required=True)
  d = fields.Float()

  @pre_dump
  def group_coordinates(self, data, many):
    data.coordinates = data
    return(data)
```